# Replacing the value of Setup with Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm mocking a `DbContext` and its `DbSet`s [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx).

I'd like to create a utility method for creating my mock `DbContext`s, which sets up each of the context's `DbSet`s to return an empty list by default (otherwise I get errors about null references whenever I try to query one of the `DbSet`s).  Then in unit tests where I want non-empty data in a certain `DbSet`, I want to call `Setup` again on that `DbSet` to supply that value than I want returned.  Code is below.

I did this in a unit test and it appears to be working, but I can't find anything about how Moq handles calling `Setup` twice on the same property.  Is doing this OK, or will it have unexpected side effects?  Using the debugger, I looked into `context.Setups`, and calling `Setup` a second time on the same property adds a second object to `Setups` rather than overwriting the first one, which worries me.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    // Creates a new Mock<MyContext> and calls Setup on each property so
    // that they all return empty lists
    private Mock<MyContext> CreateContext()
    {
        Mock<MyContext> context = new Mock<MyContext>();

        // CreateMockDbSet is a utility method which creates a Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>
        // as described in the MSDN article listed above
        context.Setup(e => e.Customers).Returns(CreateMockDbSet<Customer>().Object);
        context.Setup(e => e.Orders).Returns(CreateMockDbSet<Order>().Object);

        return context;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // By default, context.Customers and context.Orders will both return
        // empty DbSets
        Mock<MyContext> context = CreateContext();

        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order { Id = 1 },
            new Order { Id = 2 },
            new Order { Id = 3 }
        };

        // CreateMockDbSet creates a Mock<DbSet<Order>> which returns the orders
        // in 'orders'.  What does Moq do when I call Setup again on 'Orders'?
        context.Setup(e => e.Orders).Returns(CreateMockDbSet(orders).Object);

        // ... Do test ...
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: If you replace `context.Setup(e => e.Customers).Returns(CreateMockDbSet<Customer>().Object)` with a member field containing `CreateMockDbSet<Customer>().Object` and just return that value instead of creating new dataset on every call, will it help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  I'm not creating new databases right now; I'm just configuring my mock `DbContext` to return specific data in each test.

Comment: that was a typo. I meant dataset, not database.

Comment: I want to use a brand new `DbContext` and `DbSet`s within each unit test so that each test is completely self encapsulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a subsequent setup on a method and it's non-conditional (no constraints on the arguments) then it removes all previous setups for the method.

In your case where you don't have a method accepting arguments then you obviously can't add any constraints on them, so your subsequent setup will just replace the previous.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644721/setup-on-mock-not-returning-expected-value/45798105#45798105) for an explanation of the source code.

Comment: Great, that's what I was hoping it would do.  Thanks for the response.